# check_immediate usage

Tags: php, openid

I'm implementing OpenID auth on a website and I'm using check_immediate. Now it works great with every big provider (google, myopenid, aol). But when a client from 1 certain OP tries to auth i always get Auth_OpenID_SetupNeededResponse. Now I've read that in this case the RP should retry without check_immediate (correct me if im wrong). But instead the OP sends me the error and does NOT specify a setup_url.

How can I fix this? Is this an error on the OP side or RP side?

Comment: Can you say which RP this is, or paste the setup_needed response?

Comment: the RP uses the latest Janrain library for PHP

this is what the OP shows me (it stops at this page):

ns:http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
mode:setup_needed

the OP uses a modified version of dotnetopenid library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openid.setup_url` is not included in the [OpenID 2.0 specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#negative_assertions).  Only [OpenID 1.1](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html#anchor17) OPs are required to include it.  So RPs should be prepared to *not* find that parameter in the `checkid_immediate` failure response and be able to synthesize the `checkid_setup` URL themselves without any help from the OP.

Comment: Aha, so i should redo the authentication without check_immediate. The specifications were a bit sketchy on this, i understood that the OP had to take action.

Thanks for the help